# Cómo programar una función de producto(tipo sum) en SQL

Tags: sql-server

¿Existe alguna forma rápida de crear una función que haga lo mismo que la función de agregado sum, pero en vez de sumar todos los elementos numéricos de una columna los multiplique.

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT SUM(N) FROM (VALUES(1),(2)...(N))T(N)
```

Pero en vez de SUM sería PRO:

```
SELECT PRO(N) FROM (VALUES(1),(2)...(N))T(N)
```

Yo lo he hecho con una función y un cursor, es decir, recorriendo todos los elementos de una tabla y multiplicando sus valores al mismo tiempo que los acumulo. Quizá haya una forma más rápida de hacerlo con CTE's o un método que no requiera el uso de cursores. Gracias.

Por cierto, estoy utilizando SQL SERVER, pero me valdría cualquier otra BBDD SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtenerlo mediante una variable. Pero no sé que quieras hacer con eso. Además de que multiplicar números puede hacer que el valor crezca muy rápidamente.

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE( N int);

INSERT INTO @Tabla
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

DECLARE @Producto bigint = 1;

SELECT @Producto *= N
FROM @Tabla;

SELECT @Producto;
```

Comment: No conocía el operador compuesto en SQL. Gracias Luis, una respuesta muy buena.

Comment: Luis, si incluso el tipo bigint me produce desbordamiento, ¿cómo puedo trabajar con números muy grandes en SQL? Imagina por ejemplo el factorial de 64 que devuelve un nº impronunciable. ¿Tiene SQL Server posibilidad de trabajar con ese tipo de nºs? Excel sí te lo permite, devolviéndote el nº expresado en formato exponencial.  Gracias.

Comment: Olvídalo, era cuestión de asignarle el tipo float y ya me lo expresa de forma exponencial.

Comment: Recuerda que float es un dato de tipo aproximado y puede generar errores de precisión. Especialmente en números muy grandes o muy pequeños.

Comment: OK Luis, gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo yo mismo empleando, por ejemplo, este código que calcula la serie de Fibonacci:

```
with vars (a,b,i) as (
   select -1 a, 0 b, 0 i
   union all
   select b a, a+b b, i+1 from vars where i<20
)
 select -b Fibonacci from vars option(maxrecursion 1000)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Pero ahí no estás multiplicando nada, y lo que tú querías era hacer la multiplicaría según lo q tu mismo escribiste

Comment: Sí lo sé, quería referirme al concepto de recursividad para poder resolver el problema.